# Redis Booksleeve GetConfig Concern

Tags: redis, booksleeve

I'm using Redis MSOpenTech 2.6 with Booksleeve 1.3.38. Whenever I execute

```
Dictionary<string, string> config = conn.Server.GetConfig("save").Result;
```

I get the following:

```
save 900 0 300 0 60 0
```

which I know is incorrect, since I can read the .conf file and it's set to the standard

```
900 1 300 10 60 10000
```

I've tried running the command with admin privileges and without, and it's always the same. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug with the MS OpeTech version of Redis?

Comment: If you use redis-cli, what does "config get save" output?

Comment: @MarcGravell -- it says the same thing: "900 0 300 0 60 0"